# Dynamically creating classes with eval in python

Tags: python, oop, metaprogramming

I want to take an argument and create a class whose name is the argument itself.
For example, I take 'Int' as an argument and create a class whose name is 'Int',
that is my class would be like this.

```
class Int :
    def __init__(self,param) :
        self.value = 3
```

I am doing this by doing this.

```
def makeClass( x ) :

    return eval( 'class %s :\n    def __init__(self,param) :\n        self.type = 3'%(x,))
```

and then calling

```
myClass = makeClass('Int')
myInt = myClass(3)
```

I am getting a syntax error for this. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

`eval` is used for evaluating expressions, `class` is not an expression, it's a statment.  Perhaps you want something like `exec`?

As a side note, what you're doing here could probably be done pretty easily with [`type`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type), and then you sidestep all of the performance and security implications of using `eval`/`exec`.

```
def cls_init(self,param):
    self.type = 3

Int = type("Int",(object,),{'__init__':cls_init})
#           ^class name
#                ^class bases -- inherit from object.  It's a good idea :-)
#                           ^class dictionary.  This is where you add methods or class attributes.
```

Comment: Thanks, that was new. Can you point me towards a verbose example.

Comment: @noPE -- A verbose example of what?

Comment: got it. I could not see the full reply of yours, I guess. My bad.

Comment: @noPE -- Maybe.  I just edited to make it a little more verbose hoping that would clear things up.

Comment: Here is a more complete explanation of the use of `type` to create a class on the fly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/298607

Comment: @mgilson. Thanks, I was trying this for more than 3 hours :-)

Comment: Quick hack: `exec("class X:\n\tdef __eq__(s,o):return True"); x=X(); x==1 and x==2`

Answer (score 5):

As requested, this works in Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, printing `3`:

```
def makeClass(x):
    exec('class %s:\n\tdef __init__(self,v):\n\t\tself.value = v' % x)
    return eval('%s' % x)

myClass = makeClass('Int')
myInt = myClass(3)

print(myInt.value)
```

If you wish to add methods from the existing classes:

```
def makeClass(name):
    parent = name.lower()
    exec('class %s(%s):\n\tdef __init__(self,v):\n\t\tself.value = v' % (name, parent))
    return eval('%s' % name)

Int = makeClass('Int')
myInt = Int(3)

Str = makeClass('Str')
myStr = Str(3)

print(myInt.value, myInt == 3, myInt == 5)
print(myStr.value, myStr == '3', myStr == 3)
```

Output:

```
3 True False
3 True False
```

Less typing with side effects:

```
def makeClass(name):
    parent = name.lower()
    exec('global %s\nclass %s(%s):\n\tdef __init__(self,v):\n\t\tself.value = v' % (name, name, parent))

makeClass('Int')
myInt = Int(3)

makeClass('Str')
myStr = Str(3)
```

Mgilson's `type` answer is probably preferred, though.